# Itering over an array which contains arrays with key:value

Tags: javascript, firebase

I populate an array with location values from firebase:

```
    const locationArray = [];
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("locations");
    ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        locationArray.push({'lat': snapshot.val().coordinates.latitude,'lon':snapshot.val().coordinates.longitude});
    });
console.log(locationArray);
```

This results in an array, console.log(locationArray) returns:

```
491: Object { lat: "52.38254562", lon: "5.21993393" }
​​lat: "52.38254562"
​​lon: "5.21993393"
​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​492: Object { lat: "51.52156064", lon: "5.0705075" }
​493: Object { lat: "51.62715423", lon: "5.07507807" }
​494: Object { lat: "51.67663571", lon: "4.43444744" }
​495: Object { lat: "51.70944452", lon: "4.81056056" }
​496: Object { lat: "51.71126434", lon: "4.702001" }
​497: Object { lat: "51.81365373", lon: "4.89667867" }
​498: Object { lat: "51.64226434", lon: "4.74694894" }
​499: Object { lat: "51.67359367", lon: "4.81549249" }
​length: 500
​<prototype>: Array []
```

How do I iterate over this array?

locationArray.length returns 0

Itering over this array using for example for(const i in locationArray) doesn't work (0 iterations)

I even tried to make two arrays, one with longitude values and one with latitude values. But these give me also a length of zero ["51.52156064","51.62715423" etc...]

Comment: Your `console.log` says `​length: 500`. This contradicts the claim that `locationArray.length` is `0` you make in your post. Most likely, you are iterating the array at the wrong point in time: You need to iterate after it has been populated, i.e. inside the callback, otherwise it won't be populated before the callback has been called.

Comment: When did you `console.log`? Please show one block of code that includes that `console.log`. It all depends where you have it. My guess is you have executed it synchronously with the code you've show, so that you performed it too soon. Yet, console is lazy and by the time you expand the entry in the console, it has been populated.

Comment: I have edited my post. Logging at the same place returns the full array with console.log(locationArray) and 0 when I console.log(locationArray.length)

Comment: The console "updates" objects logged there retroactively - changes made to the object _after_ you logged it, can still be reflected there. My guess is that you perhaps have some sort of timing/ async issue here, introduced by that `.on("child_added", ...)` part ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is the data retrieved [asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) which means we need to process the data only after we finish fetching it.

So define a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and call it whenever change happens.

**Example:**

```js
const locations = [];
const ref = firebase.database().ref("locations");

ref.orderByKey().once("child_added").then((snapshot) => {

    /** Executes every time child (an array item) gets added to this key. */

    if (snapshot.exists()) {

        locations.push({
            'lat': snapshot.val().coordinates.latitude,
            'lon': snapshot.val().coordinates.longitude
        });

        showLocation(locations);

    } else {
        console.log("No data available");
    }

});
```

```js
function showLocation(locations) {

   for (const location of locations) {
    /** Process your location data here.. Show it in the UI */
   }
}
```